# UITextField customization

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, customization

I need a UITextField to look like this as per the client's request

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLh4Q.png

I've used a normal UITextField and even tried a cornerRadius to get it look the same but mine looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVDrP.png

One noticeable difference between the two is that in the standard UITextField there is a slight blackish line that acts as a shadow at the top part of the horizontal border of the button. How do i get rid of that?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Have you tried using a background image?

Comment: I did consider that. But i was wondering if there was anyway of doing it programmatically by customizing UITextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you must use a background image.

Here is a related post.
[Custom UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094907/custom-uitextfield)

Answer (score 2):

You can use textField borderStyle as `UITextBorderStyleNone`and `textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`.

and then use image what you want to put in the background. Keep in mind that `UIImageView` on which you are placing your image should be the lower view and `UITextField` should be your upper view.

Answer (score 1):

hide the border completely and use a custom background image (containing your desired border)!