# Add image to UITextField in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield, uipickerview

[image]

I need to implement the concept of `dropdown` in Xcode.

For that purpose, I'm using a `UIPickerview`.

This pickerView loads when a textfield is tapped (on textFieldDidBeginEditing:)event.

**Question:**

Is there a way, that I can add a image to `TextField`?

The image is like an arrow mark by which user can understand that a `dropdown` appears when `textfield` is tapped .How can I make it?

Comment: You can add a button (with your arrow image) next to your textfield to open the pickerview .

Comment: can i add something like imageview to textfield programatically?

Comment: If you don't want the user to edit the textfield, instead of textfield you can have button.

Comment: See Andrey Chernukha's answer below

Comment: It's a possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094907/custom-uitextfield

Comment: please use a button and not a textField, if the user should not type anything..

Comment: @arizah use the custom dropdown view mate, i use this in my many projects it very easy to use and best see the first link from my answer..

Answer (score 151, accepted):

UITextField has a `rightView` property, if you have image like this- [image] then You can easly set ImageView object to rightView:

```
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];

myTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
myTextField.rightView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downArrow.png"]];
```

Comment: for border plz go through with this blog http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/01/04/uitextfield-a-complete-api-overview/

Comment: If I add image left side on textField. How can we manage spacing between image and text.

Comment: @Joge you would add the image into a UIView and set the views width including the padding you want

Answer (score 39):

**In Swift:**

```
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
textField.leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "imageName"))
```

Comment: elegant solution !, but i also have some trouble to set a background image for my uitexfield (not left view, but the whole background), can you tell me how ?, in swift.

Comment: to set correct margins / padding on image, first create a view with little bit bigger dimension than image. And create the image view, center it in the UIView, add UIImageView to UIView. Now final step is to set this UIView as .leftView.

Answer (score 31):

You can put the `UIImageView` to the left of your `UITextField`.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(96, 40, 130, 20)];
[textField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
textField.leftView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchIccon.png"]];
```

Comment: Thank you Erhan, IMO your solution is the best and shortest !!! It helped me a lot :)

Comment: Your welcome Davit :) . Really I appereciate hear from you good sound :)

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3.0**

```
txtField.rightViewMode = .always
txtField.rightView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "selectdrop"))
```

[image: TextField With DropDown Icon]

Answer (score 6):

To add proper margins / paddings between image and textfield, try this below code.
Expanding on @King-Wizard's answer.

Here the height of my TextField is 44
Check the attached image for reference.

**Swift Version:**

```
emailTF.leftViewMode = .Always
let emailImgContainer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(emailTF.frame.origin.x, emailTF.frame.origin.y, 40.0, 30.0))
let emailImView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 25.0, 25.0))
emailImView.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
emailImView.center = emailImgContainer.center
emailImgContainer.addSubview(emailImView)
emailTF.leftView = emailImgContainer
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

hey mate you want dropdown view then see this custom dropdown view ..

1. http://code.google.com/p/dropdowndemo/downloads/list
2. http://ameyashetti.wordpress.com/2010/09/26/drop-down-demo/

and for this requirement use this code

```
UITextField *txtstate =[[UITextField alloc]init]; [txtstate setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30,170, 30)]; 
txtstate.delegate=self; 

txtstate.text=@"Fruits"; 

txtstate.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine; 

txtstate.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdownbtn.png"]; 

[txtstate setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo]; 
[self.view addSubview:txtstate];
```

and set your textfield border style none..

Comment: txtstate =[[UITextField alloc]init];
    [txtstate setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30,170, 30)];
    txtstate.delegate=self;
    txtstate.text=@"Fruits";
    txtstate.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;  
  txtstate.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow-Down-black-32.png"];
     [txtstate setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
     [self.view addSubview:txtstate];  
Did like this but I need borders also..How can I do it?

Comment: which you use mate?? means you use this custom dropdown??

Comment: @arizah you did checkout the demo of dropdown.. i think this is very useful dude.. and also i give the border with many type if you want to border then i post code just tell me you required the code now??

Comment: Yes I went through it ...I got it..Thanks

Comment: k mate Thanks a lot for ur words..I do have some doubts in other concepts..Can I get ur mail Id?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19977/discussion-between-arizah-and-paras-joshi)

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** Add this class to your project and add it to your textFiled's class in identity inspector,

```
class MyCustomTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var inset: CGFloat = 0

    @IBInspectable var leftImage: String = String(){
        didSet{
            leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
            leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: leftImage))
        }
    }

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds, inset, inset)
    }

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return textRectForBounds(bounds)
    }

    override func leftViewRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(CGRectMake(0, 2, 40, 40), 10, 10) //Change frame according to your needs
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Set text insets and left image from interface builder.

[image]

**Step 3:** Enjoy.

Comment: You can make leftImage of type UIImage, which will get you a nice direct image input.

Answer (score 2):

UITextField has the following property:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *background
```

example:

```
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
myTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
```

Comment: ya but how should i link this uiimage to textfield?

Answer (score 2):

```
      emailTextField.leftViewMode = .alway
    let emailImgContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 25))
    let emailImg = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
    emailImg.image = UIImage(named: "SomeIMG")
    emailImgContainer.addSubview(emailImg)
    emailTextField.leftView = emailImgContainer
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1OOz.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO :). Can you add more detail to your answer, please? That would make it easier to understand your solution. Thanks!

Comment: click That "enter image description here

" you can understand