# iOS: Why does UITextField with setCornerRadius cut off text

Tags: ios, uitextfield, rounded-corners

I'm trying to load a UITextField with rounded corners into a table view for iOS.  For the most part, everything is working fine.  However, the left-most character gets partially cut off due to the corner radius property.  Is there a way to set a margin on the text that's inputted into a UITextField, so that it displays properly?  Here's my code:

```
        textInput = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        textInput.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        textInput.placeholder = @"example@gmail.com";
        textInput.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        textInput.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
        textInput.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

        [[textInput layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
        [[textInput layer] setBorderWidth:2.3];
        [[textInput layer] setCornerRadius:15];
        [textInput setClipsToBounds: YES];
        [textInput setDelegate:self];

    [self.contentView addSubview:textInput];
        [textInput release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution.  I created a custom textfield, subclassed from `UITextField`:

```
#import "CR_customTextField.h"

@implementation CR_customTextField

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    int margin = 10;
    CGRect inset = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + margin, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width - margin, bounds.size.height);
    return inset;
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    int margin = 10;
    CGRect inset = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + margin, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width - margin, bounds.size.height);
    return inset;
}

@end
```

Comment: I was able to use the leftView of the field like it's used in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11716069/390557

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
[textInput sizeToFit];
```

it May Helps you

Comment: that shrunk the size of the UITextField considerably, and did nothing to make the inputted text more visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
   textInput.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(5, 0, 0);
```

//helps to start writing text from given pixel