# How do I get TextField like this

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I've checked properties of `UITextField` and tried out to get a design for it like below.  But I didn't succeed.

[image]

I thought to add one more `UIView` to get that black dim color which is around it.  But I didn't know whether any properties are there in `UITextField`.

What do I need to do to get the same design as above.

UPDATE : This is my code

```
    self.txtUserName = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(Padding, height/3.5, width - (Padding*2), TextFieldHeight)];
    self.txtUserName.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.txtUserName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.txtUserName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [self.txtUserName.layer setBorderColor: [[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
    [self.txtUserName.layer setBorderWidth: 5.0];
    [self.txtUserName.layer setCornerRadius:5];
```

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: I have the graphic assets and I want to utilize them programatically.

Comment: can you show ur code

Comment: I updated the question.. @Anbu

Comment: Well at minimum you need the key icon and face icon in png graphics. For background of textfield, you can either use a gradient or you can ask your designer to create such a background image for you.

Comment: I am having image but how can i add inside textField ?

Comment: You have to set it as background image. [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7748538/4029561) . Alternatively you can use pattern color with that image as background color. Rest is fine, you are setting the border correctly, just make sure it is red color instead of grey.

Comment: If [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39725015/5501940) resolved your issue, please don't forget to accept it (green tick it) :) FYI, accepting an answer leads to: - gives the answerer +15 reputation points. - gives you (asker) +2 reputation points. - And the most important thing, it gives an indication for the viewers that this answer is the appropriate solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Interface Builder:**

**Step 01 - adding the container views**: add two views (and setup the suitable constraints) and connect them to the ViewController -as IBOutlets-:
[image]

**Step 02 - adding the background gradient imageViews**: add an "ImageView" in each of containers (or "Views" if you want to create your gradient programmatically instead of images, I recommend to do it), then set set the gradient image for them, don't forget to setup the suitable constraints for them; finally, connect them to the ViewController -as IBOutlets-:
[image]

**Step 03 - adding the textfields**: add a "TextField" on top of each "ImageView", they should be the same size as the background ImageViews. make sure to change the TextFields border style to no border from the attributes inspector:

[image]

setup the suitable constraints for them, and finally, connect them to the ViewController -as IBOutlets-:

[image]

**Coding:**
Now, you need to add those lines in the "ViewDidLoad":

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // adding corner radius to the container views:
    viewUsernameContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    viewPasswordContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    // adding corner radius to the background imageviews:
    imgUsernameBackground.clipsToBounds = true
    imgUsernameBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    imgPasswordBackground.clipsToBounds = true
    imgPasswordBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 5
}
```

Run the application, it should look like this:

[image]

What about the "validation" border? you can add those lines of code for the checked textfield (adding a border for the background ImageView):

```
// adding border to the username background ImageView
imgUsernameBackground.layer.borderWidth = 2
// whatever color you want...
imgUsernameBackground.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

and finally, it should look like this:

[image]

For sure, you can play with sizes, border widths and gradient style to make it looks good for your application.

Cheers up!

Comment: Hey.. It's Great. .But u didn't talk about a little icon at the right side :\ If you say how to add it programmatically, it would be great. Thanks a lot for your help. (:

Comment: UITextField has subviews named leftView and rightView @property(nonatomic, strong) UIView *rightView;

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your `UITextFields` as subviews of separate `UIViews`.

Set the `UIView` background color to:

```
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5]
```

Then set the edge rounding using:

```
backView.clipsToBounds = YES;
backView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
```

For your `UITextFields` you can also set the clipping and corner radius. If you also want the red line use something like:

```
textView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
textView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: can't add as subview..     `[self.backView addSubview:self.txtUserName];` When i put this, UIView stands front and textField goes back

Comment: In that case you must doing something else wrong, because that's normal iOS view programming. Don't forget to set the origin of the textView's frame to something sensible - e.g. (5, 5).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Two Separate UIView

   [image: UIView]
2. For TextFields.Change Their Background color to Gray.
3. Place Text Fields on UIView.
4. And For Yellow Color,Change ViewControllers Background Color.

There You go

Hope This will Help

Comment: I am doing programmatically without using StoryBoard.

Comment: But why ..Any Specific reason ?

Comment: Yes... My whole project is created Programmatically.. Now i can't change

Answer (score 0):

You can design the `UITextField` on the `UImageView` like I did here

**My Code :**

```
UIImageView *imgVw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 40, 50)];
imgVw.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:0.4];
imgVw.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
imgVw.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:imgVw];

UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];

UITextField *txtFld = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, CGRectGetWidth(imgVw.frame) - 10, CGRectGetHeight(imgVw.frame) - 10)];
txtFld.leftView = leftView;
txtFld.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
txtFld.delegate = self;
txtFld.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
txtFld.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
txtFld.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
[imgVw addSubview:txtFld];
```

Output :

[image]

I have given some dummy color code, you can design accordingly.
Hope it helps

Happy coding ...