# UITextField rounded corner - swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

Is there anyway to fix this problem and how to put icon inside UITextField?
This is my code.

```
func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius:CGFloat) {
    let bounds = self.bounds

    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer

    let frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    frameLayer.frame = bounds
    frameLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    frameLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    frameLayer.fillColor = UIColor.init(red: 247, green: 247, blue: 247, alpha: 0).cgColor

    self.layer.addSublayer(frameLayer)
}

func roundTopCornersRadius(radius:CGFloat) {
    self.roundCorners(corners: [UIRectCorner.topLeft, UIRectCorner.topRight], radius:radius)
}

func roundBottomCornersRadius(radius:CGFloat) {
    self.roundCorners(corners: [UIRectCorner.bottomLeft, UIRectCorner.bottomRight], radius:radius)
}
```

in viewDidLoad()

```
username.roundTopCornersRadius(radius: 8)
password.roundBottomCornersRadius(radius: 8)
```

This is what i've got

[image]

i want my textField look like this

[image]

Comment: why you make struggle, crate the one view set the corner radious of that view add two textfield inside the view and set your textfield style as None

Comment: you might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721910/how-do-i-get-textfield-like-this/39725015#39725015), I think it's similar to your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an image, use the leftView property of the UITextField.

Your code for the borders seems fine, but remember to ensure that the layout of the textfield has completed before adding the cornerRadius.  You can call view.layoutIfNeeded() to ensure that it has been called.  Alternatively (the better solution), you can override `layoutSubviews()` in your custom textfield and ensure the bounds of the layer is changed when the layout of the textfield changes.

Set the textField's borderStyle to .none.

## Swift 3 Code Example

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    
    @IBInspectable
    var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }

    var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.borderStyle = .none
        setupImageView()
    }
    
    func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius:CGFloat) {
        let bounds = self.bounds
        
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
        
        let frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        frameLayer.frame = bounds
        frameLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        frameLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        frameLayer.fillColor = UIColor.init(red: 247, green: 247, blue: 247, alpha: 0).cgColor
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(frameLayer)
    }
    
    func setupImageView() {
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:5,y:0,width:35,height:25))
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.leftView = imageView
        self.leftViewMode = .always
    }


    func roundTopCornersRadius(radius:CGFloat) {
        roundCorners(corners: [UIRectCorner.topLeft, UIRectCorner.topRight], radius:radius)
    }

    func roundBottomCornersRadius(radius:CGFloat) {
        roundCorners(corners: [UIRectCorner.bottomLeft, UIRectCorner.bottomRight], radius:radius)
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement IBDesignable View

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this is really custom, not sure if you can do that with native textfield without some work.

Why not doing this instead:

An UIView that will contain your two icons and two textfields next to them :

[image]

Just make sure to set no border style to your textfield :

[image]

Then set the corner radius of the UIView that contain everything to whatever you want ;) easy mate!